# How to pass multiple arrays in exec command resource in puppet?

Tags: puppet

I want to deploy certs in default keystore using Puppet

I have two files `root.crt` and `intermediateca.crt` managed by puppet

```
$alias=[rootca, intermediateca]
$filecert= ["/var/lib/certs/rootca", "/var/lib/certs/intermediateca.crt"]

 
'/var/lib/certs/root.crt':
      source => "puppet:///modules/${module_name}/sonarqube/${::env}/var/lib/certs/root.crt",
      mode   => '0644',
      notify => Exec['install_cert'];

    '/var/lib/certs/intermediateca.crt':
      source => "puppet:///modules/${module_name}/sonarqube/${::env}/var/lib/certs/intermediateca.crt",
      mode   => '0644',
      notify => Exec['install_cert'];
```

Now for each file I want to run an exec command which should take alias array and crt file as an argument in exec command resource. I tried but it is not working

```
 exec {
    'install_cert':
      path => "/usr/bin",
      command => "keytool -importcert   -keystore ${keystore} -storepass ${storepass} -noprompt -trustcacerts",
      provider => linux,
      subscribe => File['/var/lib/certs/'],
      refreshonly => true;
  }
```

I am not sure if code above is correct or not. Can someone help?

Comment: Any reason you're not using the `puppetlabs/java_ks` module?

Answer (score 1):

The pasted code isn't really valid Puppet code, it's hard to guess what it's supposed to do. As suggested in comments a "correct" solution would be using [java-ks module](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-java_ks). Something like:

```
java_ks { 'puppetca:truststore':
  ensure       => latest,
  certificate  => '"/var/lib/certs/intermediateca.crt',
  target       => '/var/lib/certs/rootca',
  password     => 'puppet',
  trustcacerts => true,
}
```

In case you want to execute such commands manually you can use `each` to define `exec` resources:

```
$alias = ['rootca', 'intermediateca']
$alias.each |String $cert| {
  exec {"some_command_${cert}":
    command = "/bin/some/binary --arg ${cert}"
  }
}
```

Notify in file resource can't pass arguments, it will simply execute command defined in [`exec` resource](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/types/exec.html).

```
file {'/var/lib/certs/root.crt':
  source => "...",
  notify => Exec['some_command_rootca'],
}
```